sudo systemctl daemon-reload not working through ssh command
After modifying systemctl myService.service file, when command "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" is executed remotely via SSH through a bash sh script:

The myService.service file is modified correctly in remote server
But nothing happens with daemon reloading, changes are not reloaded in the remote server system.

Sample of bash sh script section:
ssh -i "/myssh.key" myuser@host "sudo bash 'echo -e \"ExecStart=/mydir/run-service.sh\" >> /etc/systemd/system/myService.service'"
ssh -i "/myssh.key" myuser@host "sudo systemctl daemon-reload"

Service file is modified correctly on remote server, but it seems daemon reload command has no effect on remote server.
However, after executing the above script, invoking "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" manually via ssh terminal session, changes are reloaded properly.
Putting the two commands separated by ; in the same ssh call don't solve the problem.
Server: Ubuntu 22.04.4
Remote client (running the sh script): Windows WSL2
Containers: no

Keep in mind that daemon-reload does not start or enable your service. It only loads the service file so that you can start or enable your service. Can you clarify whether you've tried starting/enabling your service?

Yes. Service exists and enabled+started.
Then, that script executes remotely doing these steps via ssh -i "/myssh.key" myuser@host "":

sudo systemclt stop myService.service >>>>> Succesfully executed and service stopped
Modify some values in /etc/systemdsystem/myService.service file >>>> The resulting file is valid
sudo systemctl daemon-reload >>>>>>> Executed correctly, showing no errors
sudo systemctl start myService.service >>>>>> myServices is started successfully and stays running again BUT running service didn't notice of changes to myService.service file


Then, if I go to the server vía ssh session and exec "sudo systemctl stop myService.service", then "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" and lastly "sudo systemctl start myService.service", the changes made to file myService.service when executing the script are applied to the new running.
So, it seems a problem when doing the daemon reload throught ssh -i "/myssh.key" myuser@host "sudo systemctl daemon-reload"

Thanks for clarifying. I wonder if you're running into a race condition between daemon-reload and start. Can you add a sleep 10 to your script after daemon-reload to test this idea?

Tested. The adding of 10s delay between the calls resolved the problem:
ssh -i "/myssh.key" myuser@host "sudo bash 'echo -e \"ExecStart=/mydir/run-service.sh\" >> /etc/systemd/system/myService.service'"
sleep 10s
ssh -i "/myssh.key" myuser@host "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" 

SOLVED
As suggested by Nick ODell, adding a sleep 10s between commands solved the problem:

ssh -i "/myssh.key" myuser@host "sudo bash 'echo -e \"ExecStart=/mydir/run-service.sh\" >> /etc/systemd/system/myService.service'"
sleep 10s
ssh -i "/myssh.key" myuser@host "sudo systemctl daemon-reload"

